# why i am not getting chromedriver exception in python

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the following code.

```
import pytest
import time
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#login
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("url")
#time.sleep(10)
driver.set_window_size(920, 680)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "loginUserName").send_keys("xx")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "loginPassword").send_keys("yy")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "loginButton").click()
```

**It is working fine for me and i'm not included any path and set property for chrome-extension.** If i share this program,the opposite person is getting the following error and they have chromedriver.exe in python folder and in that same folder they created this python file

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\1025043\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\anu\1.py",
>   line 8, in 
>       driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path) NameError: name 'chrome_driver_path' is not defined

In my path i am having,

> ['',
>   'C:\Users\1024983\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.zip',
>   'C:\Users\1024983\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs',
>   'C:\Users\1024983\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib',
>   'C:\Users\1024983\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37', 
>   'C:\Users\1024983\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages',
>   'C:\Users\1024983\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32',
>   'C:\Users\1024983\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
>   'C:\Users\1024983\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin']

What is the reason for this.?

Note: I am using Windows 10, Python 3.7.4 ,selenium 3.141.0 ,Chrome Version 78.0.3904.108(opposite person also using this version only)

Comment: `chromedriver.exe` needs to be in the path, it is in your computer so it works.

Comment: In opposite person's system also they have exe in python folder and in that same folder they created .py file..

Comment: So the code itself is running from different locations, or you added it to the system PATH manually. To avoid such problem add the `chromedriver` to the project and include relative path to it.

Comment: nope i am not included in environment variable and project home also

Answer (score 0):

The chromedriver.exe should be included in the executable PATH.
Download the chromedriver.exe and add this to the code as below. (add chrome driver path as it's located in your machine) or you can include in to the PATH variable in environment variables in windows 10.

E.g.

```
import pytest
import time
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#login
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("url")
#time.sleep(10)
driver.set_window_size(920, 680)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "loginUserName").send_keys("xx")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "loginPassword").send_keys("yy")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "loginButton").click()
```

Comment: But without  "driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver.exe')" my code is working..that is what my question is ?

Comment: Did you include that `chromedriver.exe` into the project home or added to the **PATH** variable in environment variables?

Comment: nope i am not included in environment variable and project home also..That's why i am wondering

Comment: This can't be worked without having the chromedriver.exe. Therefore could you please double-check by printing the path as below, `import sys
print(sys.path)`

Comment: i have attached my path..please look into it and please let me know which is used to  chromedriver.exe...I am not clear

Comment: You can check whether the chromedriver.exe has been set to the path without your awareness by runnung below command in cmd. `chromeDriver -v`

Comment: check this "https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started". chromedriver.exe need to be specified or set to the PATH variable to work the programs. Thus it may be set in you machine without your awareness. Therefore try to find the location of chromedriver.exe which is located in your machine by cmd commands.